# axis X line not showing below bar

Tags: core-plot

Why isn't the axis X line continuous ?

Below each bar, the line doesn't appear.

What should i do ?

Below is the image of the problem

[image: Image showing the problem]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar plot layer is on top of the axes by default. It looks like the bars extend below the axis, covering up part of the line. Check the "base value" of the bar plot.